# When Betelgeuse goes supernova, will the explosion hit any neighboring stars?

Tags: star, supernova, betelgeuse

There is evidence Betelgeuse might go supernova "soon". Are there any stars in the vicinity of Betelgeuse that are close enough that they will be hit by the explosion of this supernova? What would be the effect on stars near Betelgeuse?

---

A supernova "kicks" out the other star if it is in a binary pair, but Betelgeuse is not a binary, so [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/25357/what-happens-to-the-neighboring-star-of-a-type-ia-supernova) doesn't quite answer the question.

Comment: A related question on Physics.SE: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/455526/123208

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There have been 2 proposed spectroscopic companions, though never confirmed, traveling with Betelgeuse. These are thought to orbit the red supergiant. So when Betelgeuse eventually explodes, they would  certainly be blasted by radiation, atmospheres could be damaged or completely destroyed, and would lose their host star sending them on a new trajectory through space.  But with Betelgeuse having been ejected from its birth place and  traveling with no verified companion, its more likely that the surrounding galaxy would be left unchanged, aside from  supernova remnant left behind.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betelgeuse has more information if you still have questions.

Comment: To clarify why I mentioned the unconfirmed companions, they were a way to briefly say a few of the effects caused by a supernova on nearby objects.

Comment: You can use the edit button to add that to your question if you would like.

Comment: Thank you, first day here so feeling things out.

Comment: Welcome to Astronomy.SE!  We certainly hope you stick around!

Comment: Much appreciated!